# eclipse not run my existing android project...?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've made android phonegap application in my eclipse, it work really fine till now. But I think latest update of Android SDK cause failing of existing project to run.

[image]

Here in second screenshot you can find, when I right click on project Run As->Run Configurations. When I click on **Browse**, no project visible in project selection window.
[image]

Comment: you've hidden the project name in project explorer but you forgot to hide it on eclipse window panel :)

Comment: try restarting you eclipse if didn't tried yet...

Comment: What do you see when you right click on the project name in project explorer and go to 'run as...'?

Comment: check your file project first before you hit run app as